# Ruby gem failed to open TCP connection to localhost:1080

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll on my Windows 10 computer. I have installed [Ruby+Devkit](https://rubyinstaller.org) successfully and their versions are:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
$ gem -v
3.3.3
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.3.3
```

But when I ran any of these commands:

```
$ gem install jekyll
```

or

```
$ gem sources --add https://gems.ruby-china.com/ --remove https://rubygems.org/
```

or

```
$ bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org https://gems.ruby-china.com
$ cd my-jekyll-repo
$ bundle install
```

or

```
ridk install
```

I was prompted with errors all including the message

```
Net::OpenTimeout: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:1080 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - user specified timeout) (https://gems.ruby-china.com/specs.4.8.gz)
```

While I have installed Jekyll on other Windows 10 computers successfuly before I've never seen this error. I've searched in many places but couldn't find a solution. I don't understand why it's trying to connect to `localhost:1080` but I tried to open the port from the firewall inbound rules as per this [instruction](https://frameboxxindore.com/windows/how-to-open-a-port-in-windows.html) and it doesn't work.

Comment: You have a proxy or some sort of VPN setup? Port 1080 is a SOCKS proxy port.

Comment: @Casper I'm on a company computer which is connected to the company domain. I don't see any proxy or VPN setting in the settings on this computer. I can connect to the internet with no problem (except websites blocked in the region). I can visit the mirror site `https://gems.ruby-china.com` with Chrome and ping it in CMD with success. Actually I can visit and ping `https://rubygems.org/` as well. I thought I couldn't ...

Comment: It's very difficult to troubleshoot something like this remotely. But you can try and run `printenv | grep -i proxy`, and see if you have any ENV variables activated for proxy settings. In any case I am quite certain based on your error message, that somewhere in your system a proxy setting, switch, environment variable, or other setting has been activated. There is no other explanation for what you are seeing.

Comment: Please also edit your question with the FULL output of all error messages that you see. There may be other clues in the error output Always post full error output. Thanks.

Comment: @Casper Ooooops I just recall I've set the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` to `localhost:1080` months ago. After removing them things proceed well now! Thanks for your support!